# Orthogonal projection on span $x$

Tags: matrices

If $x = (2,1)$ and $y = (1,-1)$ how can I find orthogonal projection on the span of $x$? And projection on the span of $x$ along the span of $y$?

What I have done is, for the first question, I did $x((x^Tx)^{-1})x^T$ (where the $^T$ is transpose) and for the second question, I used $\dfrac{xy}{|y^2|}y$.

But I think I totally got the wrong idea. Can you guys help me to figure out this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Since we're working in two dimensions, think about what this situation looks like visually. What does the span of x look like? the span of y?

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonal projection of $w$ onto the span of $x$ (take $\{\frac{1}{||x||}x\}$ to be an orthonormal basis for the span of $x$) is

$\langle w,\frac{1}{||x||}x\rangle\frac{1}{||x||}x$.

Your expression for the second part therefore is right, provided the square is outside the vertical bar enclosing $y$, and the inner product $\langle ,\rangle$ is the dot product.

Comment: You can get the correct brackets in MathJax using \langle and \rangle: $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.